# ViewController, который задаётся кодом

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

В одной библиотеке наткнулся на `View Controller`, который задаётся исключительно с помощью кода, то есть, `Storyboard` там нет. Но мне нужно настроить переходы от одного `View Controller` к другому и так далее. И вот как настраивать такой VC?

Прилагаю код (с помощью него строится график):

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class MainViewController: UIViewController, LineChartDelegate {



var label = UILabel()
var lineChart: LineChart!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var views: [String: AnyObject] = [:]

    label.text = "..."
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    self.view.addSubview(label)
    views["label"] = label


view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[label]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-80-[label]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))

    // simple arrays
    let data: [CGFloat] = [3, 4, -2, 11, 13, 15]
    let data2: [CGFloat] = [1, 3, 5, 13, 17, 20]

    // simple line with custom x axis labels
    let xLabels: [String] = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]

    lineChart = LineChart()
    lineChart.animation.enabled = true
    lineChart.area = true
    lineChart.x.labels.visible = true
    lineChart.x.grid.count = 1
    lineChart.y.grid.count = 1
    lineChart.x.labels.values = xLabels
    lineChart.y.labels.visible = true
    lineChart.addLine(data)
    lineChart.addLine(data2)

    lineChart.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    lineChart.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(lineChart)
    views["chart"] = lineChart
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[chart]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[label]-[chart(==200)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}



/**
 * Line chart delegate method.
 */
func didSelectDataPoint(_ x: CGFloat, yValues: Array<CGFloat>) {
    label.text = "x: \(x)     y: \(yValues)"
}



/**
 * Redraw chart on device rotation.
 */
override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    if let chart = lineChart {
        chart.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, вы хотите перейти на этот самый MainViewController с другого VC.

```
let mainViewController = MainViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainViewController, animated: true)
```